# Filtering folders and files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code - and some of the files in my explorer view are greyed out.
That's useful because, to the best of my knowledge, it means Visual Studio Code is communicating that these are the files that are not detected by git.

However, without crawling the entire tree, I'm not sure which files will be skipped.
So - if there is a file buried in a folder, unless I manually navigate there, I won't know it's being skipped.

And I'd like to able to directly see in VSC which files will be greyed out without manually navigating.

So, is there a term or phrase I can use in the Search field to discover them?

Comment: Are you using the GitLens extension?

Comment: I am not - i will look into; ty for the question

Comment: I was wrong (the little "Installed" wasn't there) - it's installed globally.

Is there some aspect of this extension that you feel will address my request?

Comment: Was just trying to get more information to see if this is base VSCode functionality you're talking about or something to do with a third-party extension. Not actually sure if there's a feature which does what you're asking, but best of luck getting an answer!

Comment: then you need to take a close look at your `.gitignore` and refine the dirs if needed, otherwise you have to crawl through a lot of files line all the `node_modules`

Comment: @rioV8 - that was precisely what i was trying to not have to do; it would be amazing if we could search by meta-data. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @MihaiChelaru - although the response to my post seems to be identifying how the files are greyed out, the aggregate take is clear - search does not currently lend itself to meta-data. Thanks for the response!